# containerd-shim-runc-v2 consumes my GPU RAM

Tags: docker, runc

Lately I added NVIDIA GPU card to an Ubuntu 22.04.  The system keep crashing soon after the card's memory is fully consumed by uwsgi processes.  When tracking the parent process for it, I see its because containerd-shim-runc-v2.

root        2923       1  0 18:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace moby -id 6aa32ee25cc8c173dc8cfbaa4c401769feecc389e300e9cab0ac51c35f459de6 -address /run/containerd/containerd.sock

Can anyone help me understand how to configure containerd-shim-runc-v2 not to use GPU at all?

Thanks,

Tal.

Answer (score 0):

Found it was CompreFace within a Docker compose.